# Linecolor of active line in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to highlight the current line in a text area with a background color?

Example:

[image]

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  background-color: #202020;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<textarea spellcheck="false">
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
</textarea>
```

Comment: Yes its possible, what have you tried so far? Please explain why that specific line would be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the script here but it didn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/c6hzg08d/ I use a text field for work instructions and because the textarea is going to get big you can immediately see where you are when you switch screens.

Comment: It's quite problematic to alter the styling of text in a text area. Could you explain what you mean by 'current line' - is it the one with the cursor in it? Will your text area width always be fixed or it there some responsiveness? Finding the 'line' is the first of the problems as the line breaks have been decided by CSS (I assume?)

Comment: Current line is indeed the line where the cursor is in. Textarea width is fixed.

Comment: Looks like jsfilldle is working for me. May be I am missing something.

Comment: Let us know what is not working in JSfiddle: https://nimb.ws/K82sc3

Answer (score 0):

It is quite tricky formatting text within a textarea element.

This snippet takes a slightly different direction, it puts a div behind the textarea and on each keyup (and click) it finds the position of the caret (start of the selection) and copies characters from the textarea to the div up to that point, substituting the `<br>` for the newline (decimal value 10) character.

The div expands in height as lines are added or CSS decides it needs to do a line break. The div has a background image which is a linear gradient of 20px red from the bottom, this means its last line is highlighted and it will move up and down as things are deleted/added to the textarea.

```js
function keyupnclick() {
  highlight.innerHTML = '';
  let x = textarea.selectionStart;
  let str = '';
  let i = 0;
  for (i; i <= x; i++) {
    let ch = textarea.value[i];
    let chcode = textarea.value.charCodeAt(i);
    if (chcode == 10) {
      ch = '<br>';
    }
    str = str + ch;
  }
  highlight.innerHTML = str;
}
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const highlight = document.querySelector('.highlight');
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', keyupnclick);
textarea.addEventListener('click', keyupnclick);
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #202020;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.highlight,
textarea {
  /* ensure the highlighted div and the textarea have the same izing styles */
  font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, red 0, red 20px, transparent 20px, transparent 100%);
  color: transparent;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="highlight"></div>
  <textarea spellcheck="false">
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
</textarea>
</div>
```

Note: the highight div and the textarea are inside a div of the same dimensions as textarea in order to get the background gray color.